# Ubuntu 16.04 legacy mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Флешка с Ubuntu видна в биосе только с legacy mode. Когда его включаю и перезагружаюсь - получаю черный экран с мигающим курсором.

Вопрос в том, как запустить Ubuntu с флешки? Образ делал через Unetbootin на win 10

Comment: Через rufus пробовал?

Comment: @donRumata через ultraISO записал и включил нужный мод. Невнимательность... Спасибо